# save,load and update win count using NSUserDefaults in objective c

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults

I have two scenes - in `GameScene` I get win count and save it to `BonusScene`, every thing works fine, but I want to display win count on `GameScene` every time, I restart app in `BonusScene` it show up right count, but in `GameScene` it starts with 1. Here are what I have been using:   **GameScene.m**

```
-(void)winCount{
win++;
winningCount =winningCount +win;
NSLog(@"%i",win);
NSUserDefaults *scoreprefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[scoreprefs setInteger:winningCount forKey:@"winningCount"];

winLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"ROTORcapExtendedBold"];
winLabel .fontSize = 70.f;
winLabel .position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)+(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)/2),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
winLabel .zPosition = 5;
winLabel .text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)winningCount];
[self addChild:winLabel];
```

And in **BonusScene.m**

```
@implementation BonusScene
@synthesize winningCount;
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size{
NSUserDefaults *scoreprefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self = [super initWithSize:size];
if (self){
winningCount =[scoreprefs integerForKey:@"winningCount"];
    SKLabelNode *wins = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"ROTORcap Extended Bold"];
    wins.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)winningCount ];
    wins.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 100,(CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)) + self.frame.size.height/4 );
    wins.fontSize = 15.f;
    [self addChild:wins]
```

How can I update it in `GameScene` so it will show same result as in `BonusScene`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your game scene with

```
-(void)winCount{
   // get previous count first
    winningCount =[scoreprefs integerForKey:@"winningCount"];
    win++;
    winningCount = winningCount + win;
    NSLog(@"%i",win);
    // other code of the function
```